# Маленький вопрос по смене шрифта

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет!
Есть простой JS-скрипт: [Эффект матрицы с использованием HTML5 canvas](http://imapo.ru/%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-html5-canvas/).
Не получается поменять шрифт.
В CSS пишу:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
#q {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
```

...
ноль внимания, фунт презрения. (
Подскажите как сделать?

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), в котором мы могли бы сами увидеть ноль внимания и фунт презрения. Сейчас этот оторванный кусок CSS мало о чём говорит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не будет оно так работать, ибо это канвас.
В css файл пропишите только

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
```

А в самом скрипте функция draw должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var draw = function () {
q.getContext('2d').fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.05)';
q.getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
q.getContext('2d').fillStyle = '#0e0';
q.getContext('2d').font="10px Indie flower";
letters.map(function (y_pos, index) {
    text = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.random() * 33);
    x_pos = index * 10;
    q.getContext('2d').fillText(text, x_pos, y_pos);
    letters[index] = (y_pos > 758 + Math.random() * 1e4) ? 0 : y_pos + 10;
});
};
```

Собственно в самом скрипте Вы и укажете все свойства шрифта

Comment: Одна строчка... Спасибо! ) Я догадывался что править нужно сам скрипт, но...